# Facebook FQL - get all photos which user and user's friend commented, liked

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-fql

I have id of current user (uid1), and id of his friend (uid2).
How can i get photos which're liked or commented by them (using FQL).
Please help me. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For photo liked:

```
select object_id from like where object_type=photo AND user_id = {user_id}
```

For comments, this should work but it doesn't seems

```
select post_id from stream where type=46 AND source_id={user_id}
```